# Combining 2 regex expressions

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to try and combine 2 regex expressions.

```
$test = preg_replace('/\[.*?\]/', '', $test);
```

I use this to remove any square brackets and words in between the brackets..

```
$test = preg_replace ('/[\[\]=]+/', '', $test);
```

I use this  to strip any = [ ] symbols from my string.

doing this individually seems to be fine, but I'd like to combine them.
Any ideas how I can do that.. everything I've tried has broken both..

Thanks

Comment: The first of the two will strip out square brackets and everything between them.  The second one will remove `=` symbols.  Not sure if this is what you really want, but to combine the two, you can just use `|` to indicate _or_.

Comment: Which one do you execute first? The order will affect the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
$test = preg_replace('/\[.*?\]|[\[\]=]/', '', $test);
```

The ordering is here important, so that at first matching brackets, and their content, are removed. This should work fine as long as there are no nested brackets.

So, this expression will match either `\[.*?\]` **OR** `[\[\]=]`

Comment: I believe he has that to remove stray (unmatched) brackets

Comment: @Dave, OK that could be. I changed my answer a bit.

Comment: This is almost perfect :)

However if `$test = "=[TEST]Wo=rd"` it returns `TESTWord` not `Word`

Anyway to sort that ?

Comment: @user1932360, I found the problem. It is because of the `+` in the second alternation. It matches at first the "=" then continues in the second alternation because of the quantifier. If you remove the `+` it is working. Just doing maybe some more replace operations on continuous special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer is to use an or:

```
'/\[[^\]]*\]|[\[\]=]+/'
```

Notice that I also changed the inner pattern in the first string. I'm not sure if the backslash is needed there.

Comment: It is not as simple as putting the 2 regex together. You have to mind the order of which one comes first in the expression, since the behavior will be different when you swap them around.

Comment: @mhahtdh can you give an example? I can't think of one for this case (where he is erasing all matches)

Comment: `[abc]` is one good example. Just test it with the 2 pieces in alternation swapped.

Comment: The ordering is important in an alternation. From a string "Foo [test] bar" your expression will match at first only the opening bracket `[` and remove it, and it will not match and remove the content.